# Should static variables be used in a class that only gets instantiated once

Tags: java, static, conventions

I am creating a game in Java. I have this Director class which sets up my game thread and mostly deals with how the game operates. The class never should and is not instantiated more than once. Should the variables inside the class be static variables or not? I'm curious about what the java coding convention(if not every other object-orientated language) would be for something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: You are describing a singleton. There is useful info on the various options for implementing them at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, member variables shouldn't be `static`. The only thing relevant is that you need a single instance of `Director` class to manage your job, which could or couldn't be `static` according to your code.

Now, if you don't need access to `Director` instance from all around your code then you can just keep an instance somewhere, otherwise a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern could be useful. This is a pattern that manages a single instance of a class accessible from everywhere in your code.

Something like:

```
class Director {
  private static Director director;

  private Director() {
   ...
  }

  public static Director getInstance() {
    if (director == null)
      director = new Director();

    return director;
  }
}
```

Comment: So does the same apply when the only thing I really do with the class is instantiate it? Like I don't call any of its methods or anything.

Comment: If you don't call any method of the `class` from anywhere outside it then allocating it in `void main(String[] args)` would be enough since it will survive until the exit of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

What you are looking at is [Singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) design pattern, in which, it isn't necessary for member variables to be static.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I saw the singleton design pattern in other questions but those typically were talking about static classes which I am pretty sure I don't have.